# Using Git LFS : what are the best practice for local repositories?

Tags: git-lfs

I would like to use Git LFS on a project that would be shared amongst several dev teams.
The remote repo would be on our GitLab server, i want collaboration on this project but the estimated size will be around 1Tb and i don't want to force each dev to clone 1Tb data on their local disk. (Plus they won't have enough disk space on their PCs anyway...)

I was wondering if this would be correct : each team clone the remote repo on a network drive they own. Each dev of a team would then work on that drive, so they all use the same "local" repo.

Thanks you for your feedback about this, and if it seems incorrect, what would be OK then ?

Comment: Note: [tag:git-lfs] has its own tag; the tag [tag:repo] is for the old Google tool that was for Android development a decade ago (the tool still exists but Google themselves seem to have abandoned it).

Comment: Git in general, regardless of whether you're using the LFS wrappers around it, "wants" to work locally. If the project size is about 1 TB, you might want to have everyone put some medium size modern disk drives in their systems so they all have 8 TB+ of space. Newegg show some 8 TB SATA drives on sale for $140 each  right now. 4 TB is $80. WD Red drives are $85 for 4 TB...